# wget download only certain folders from site

Tags: wget

I want to download [this site](http://www.s-manuals.com/smd/) with wget, and to do this I'm using this command:

```
wget.exe --no-clobber --no-parent -r --convert-links --page-requisites -U Mozilla "http://www.s-manuals.com/smd/"
```

That's ok for me, but the linked PDF files are located in a folder in the same level of my URL example:

```
http://www.s-manuals.com/pdf/datasheet/a/f/afn3400_alpha-mos.pdf
```

So I need to download the `/pdf/` folder too. The issue is that if its in the same level dir the `--no-parent` options avoid this dir, but if I remove the `--no-parent` the entire site is going to be downloaded, so I'm wondering if there is a option that allow me to download only these 2 folders?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `--include` option instead of `--no-parent` to specify particular directories to be included in the download:

```
wget.exe --no-clobber -I /smd,/pdf -r --convert-links --page-requisites -U Mozilla "http://www.s-manuals.com/smd/"
```

See the [documentation for directory-based limits](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/html_node/Directory_002dBased-Limits.html) for more details.